# How can I update different arguments to the same function?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a function `R(t)` defined as:

```
def R(t) :
    if t > 0 :
        return "R"
    else :
        return 0
```

Now, I want to have several instances of this function working at once. For example, whenever a given condition is met, I would like to generate an `R(2)` and then, for every iteration of a for loop, I would like to subtract 1 from the argument. My problem comes when the condition is met several times in distinct iterations of the loop, so while there might be an `R(2)` just appearing, there will be an `R(1)` turning into an `R(0)`. 

I am barely learning how to use python, but I don't think that the code enabling me from accomplishing what I want is very hard. I believe that maybe if I define `R(t,j)` and use `j`as an indexing parameter it might be easier to code.

Comment: *several instances of this function* - You lost me there. Can you please explain?

Comment: In my code I am working with a column vector, so every time a condition is met, one more of the entries must turn into an instance of `R(t)`. However, as the for loop continues, the `t` must act like a sort of clock, counting down to zero every iteration of the loop. Then, at another point of the loop, the condition might be met again and another set of entries must turn into `R(t)` at the "starting time", from which it must again count down to zero with every iteration of the loop.

Comment: Please show an example input and output. Your description is rather hard to understand.

Comment: just for example if you call `R(2)` should the output be `R R 0`

Comment: @VigneshKalai yes, say for `for t in range(0,2) print R(t)` would return `0 "R"`

Comment: You could use for loop or recursive function for this

Comment: @GuachoPerez you can add the same for loop in the function write `i.e.) def(R):for a in R:your code here`

Answer (score 1):

A recursive function that does what you want is:

```
def R(t):
if t > 0:
    print "R"
    return R(t-1)
else:
    print t
```